# Trouble Sending Query to Database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I want to delete 3 fields from my database when I click on a button: `fk_id_band`, `id_band` and `band`.

But I'm having trouble sending the mysql query from my PHP file to the database.

I have this PHP code:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include('database.php');

    $id = $_SESSION['id'];

    $select = "SELECT *
    FROM users
    WHERE id_user = ".$id."";

    $result = mysql_query($select);

    $line = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    $idband = $line["fk_id_band"];


    $sqldelete = "DELETE bands
    FROM bands
    WHERE id_band = ".$idband."";

    echo $sqldelete;

    mysql_query($sqldelete);                                                                                                                                                      
?>
```

When I insert the query in phpmyadmin, it works. `(DELETE bands FROM bands WHERE id_band = 1)`

However, when I use `mysql_query($sqldelete)`, it doesn't automatically update the database as I think it should.

What's wrong here?

Comment: Try changing the last line to `mysql_query($sqldelete) or die(mysql_error());` This will show any errors that MySQL returns.

Comment: You don't need two queries. `DELETE bands FROM bands JOIN users ON id_band = fk_id_band WHERE id_user = $id`

Comment: @Barmar thanks! It says: "Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails". What should I do?

Comment: That means there's another table with a foreign key pointing to that row. You have to delete those rows first. If you want the database to delete them automatically, you can use the `ON DELETE CASCADE` option when creating the foreign key constraint in those tables.

Comment: @Barmar's answer is correct. Just wanted to add that if you are 100% sure the foreign key constraint does not matter, you can do the following to ignore foreign keys: SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; DELETE bands FROM bands JOIN users ON id_band = fk_id_band WHERE id_user = $id; SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;. But try not to do it, as it will leave your database in an inconsistent state.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar. All working now. But how do I also delete the foreign key? (all in one query)

Comment: You can delete from multiple tables with `DELETE bands.*, users.* FROM ...`

Comment: @Barmar When I do DELETE users.*, it deletes the whole user row. But when I do DELETE users.fk_id_band, it says "Unknown table 'fk_id_band' in MULTI DELETE"...

Comment: You can't delete just a column, I thought you wanted to delete the whole row. If you're not deleting the row, you have to use an `UPDATE` to set that column to some other valid ID.

Comment: There's no way to do that automatically, how is it supposed to know which new ID to refer to?

Comment: You can use `ON DELETE SET NULL` in the foreign key constraint. Try taking a little initiative and reading the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

you have syntax error in your delete statement

```
$id = $_SESSION['id'];

$select = "select * from users WHERE ID = $id";
$result = mysql_query($select); 
$line = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 

 $idband = $line["fk_id_band"];
 $sqldelete = "DELETE bands
 FROM bands
WHERE id_band = ".$idband;
echo $sqldelete;

mysql_query($sqldelete);
```

Comment: There's no difference in your `DELETE` statement. All you did was remove `.""`. That concatenates an empty string, which doesn't have any effect.